# Spyder IDE not displaying inline graphs using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I can't seem to get spyder/matplotlib to display an inline graph. The dataframe is a simple dataframe with an index, a categorical variable column, and a numerical variable column. The plot that I'd like to display is just a simple bar plot in descending order.

Code:

```
bar_plot2 = retailerDF.plot(kind='bar')
bar_plot2.show()
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'show'
```

I've tried a variety of different trouble shooting methods, but none have seemed to work. I've toggled and changed the inline settings in spyder several times and of course I've googled the error code, but none of the methods I've tried have worked .

Looking for a pointer in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does `type(bar_plot2 )` yield? It's probably a wrong object

Answer (score 0):

> what does type(bar_plot2) yield? It's probably a wrong object!

To render a graph you dont need to use the varaible to call the `show()` method. Calling `.plot()` alone would suffice.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# a simple line plot
df.plot(kind='bar')

# the plot gets saved to 'output.png'
plt.savefig('output.png')
```

You can see good examples from here - [Plot column values as bar plot](https://queirozf.com/entries/pandas-dataframe-plot-examples-with-matplotlib-pyplot#plot-column-values-as-bar-plot)